# Make a UITextField with rounded ends

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

How can I make a `UITextField` which is round and looks similar to the one used when we want to bookmark something in iOS? I believe you have to edit the text field programmatically or something.

Comment: I think your answer is <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968118/how-do-i-change-the-uitextfield-so-it-looks-like-the-search-text-field"> here ! </a>. In that example he designs his own rounded UITextField. Good Luck !

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the UITextField so it looks like the Search Text Field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968118/how-do-i-change-the-uitextfield-so-it-looks-like-the-search-text-field)

Answer (score 3):

Use `UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect`, either by setting this in the IB or programmatically.

Comment: But i want something similar to what is done in safari for ios bookmarking

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little new to iOS and was trying to figure out the same thing and Google brought up this first, so I thought I'd point other newbies to this related question: [How can i make a more rounded UITextField? Like the search field in Safari on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520050/how-can-i-make-a-more-rounded-uitextfield-like-the-search-field-in-safari-on-ip). From that question I learned that what I wanted was a [UISearchBar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (which can be added in the IB). You'll probably have to pull off some sort of trickery if you don't like the magnifying glass, but otherwise that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make custom image and set in background of that text field.